# How to find the sum of particular rows

Tags: excel, vba

How to find the sum of particular rows, before that I should find the rows by column names

Like below in image, I will be having a table from which I need to

1. Find the columns by column names
2. after finding the column names, sum should be done at last+1 column
   (Like total of "Sum of Arrears-Basic"+"Sum of Basic"+"Sum of Arrears-HouseRentAllowance")

[image]

*Dynamically means column names may varies every month so i should do loop through the column names and find which columns are available and that columns i should find the sum at last column

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-19]:RC[-13])"  instead of this i need to do this dynamically

Comment: Please explain everything within your question ([edit]). What do you mean by "dynamically"? Also I see no column names that you are talking about. Please be much more specific. Maybe include a screenshot if it helps you to explain it better. Try to give us a full example and show what you have tried so far. Reading [mcve] could help to improve your question.

Comment: Sorry, i am a beginner and hence forth i will try to ask my questions clearly....

Comment: This should give you a start: [5 Different Ways to Find The Last Row or Last Column Using VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba). Try something on your own and then come back with your code and a question to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've added your data to range `A1:D5` and I'm outputting the totals to range `E2:E5` using the following macro.

```
Sub addTotals()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("E2:E5").Formula = "=SUM(A2:D2)"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i need that in vba code were it will search for the column name , and find basic,hra,pf are their and then it should add all those values in last column